# pandas error tokenizing data, CSV data can be opened fine with any program

Tags: python, pandas

Problem is simple. My csv data can be opened with any program, no errors, nothing. But when I open with Pandas, even if I delete that respective row, I still get this following error:

Here is my CSV data:
    https://pastebin.com/yWu5PyK7

```
df = pd.read_csv('../Documents/SATELLITE_DATA.csv', delimiter=';')

#

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3f1a7ea6a732> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv('http://localhost:8888/edit/Documents/SATELLITE_DATA.csv', delimiter=';')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    701 
--> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    703 
    704     parser_f.__name__ = name

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    433 
    434     try:
--> 435         data = parser.read(nrows)
    436     finally:
    437         parser.close()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1137     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1138         nrows = _validate_integer('nrows', nrows)
-> 1139         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1140 
   1141         # May alter columns / col_dict

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1993     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1994         try:
-> 1995             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1996         except StopIteration:
   1997             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 82, s
```

Comment: For me your data working nice :)

Comment: @jezrael i am using pandas inside jupyter notebook, if that helps..

Comment: Is possible share your file? Because it seems data related problem.

Comment: here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=85696717185460515809

Comment: @MikaelKen I tried opening your file using pandas inside jupyter notebook, using the same line of code. It's still working fine.